# Swift edgeLoopForRect physics body not getting categoryBitMask correctly

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a body with `edgeLoopForRect` and I'm giving it a `categoryBitMask` but when I'm debugging the object's `categoryBitMask` is different than what I assigned it...

```
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
```

when I'm debugging its showing up as `453453` not ``

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign physics bodies to self. you have to create a node first and then assign a category bit mask to its physics body.

IE:

```html
let edge = SKNode()

edge.phisicsbody = SKPhisicsbody(edgeloopfromrect: frame)
edge.physicsbody!.restitution = 0 
edge.physicsbody!.friction = 0 
edge.physicsbody!.angularDamping = 1
edge.physicsbody!.dynamic = false
edge.physicsbody!.categotyBitMask = 2
edge.physicsbody!.collisionBitMask = 1 //The category bit mask of the object you want it to collide with I used 1 as example

addChild(edge)
```

Remember to follow the same procedure for the node that you want to collide with the edge and make the collision bit mask 2 if you follow this example.

Hope this helps mate.